# Trouble with Java scanners, printing in while loops

Tags: java, while-loop

This code takes integers as input until a non-integer is entered. The highest and lowest inputs are then printed. As-is, the code works.

From the inital print statement to first complete iteration of the while loop, why doesn't it print "Enter an integer: " more than once (the first time before the loop and again after in.hasNextInt() returns true)?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MaxMinPrinter
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");

           while (in.hasNextInt()){
               System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
               int x = in.nextInt();
               if (x > max){max = x;}
               if (x < min){min = x;}
           }
           System.out.println(max);
           System.out.println(min);

        }
    }
```

I was under the impression that this code should i) print, then ii) ask for input to enter the while loop, followed by iii) a second print and iv) moving of the scanner's "cursor" to the next token and potentially assigning new max or minimum values. Why doesnt a second print occur on the first iteration? Or am I misunderstanding the usage of the scanner class?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tested your code.working fine.Whats the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I mentioned above that the code worked, thats not the problem. I was wondering why it doesnt print the statement "Enter an integer: " twice on the first iteration of the while loop.

Comment: `hasNextInt()` is a blocking call. It will block until a token comes in the input stream.

Comment: Thanks. So, the code prints "Enter an integer: " the first time, before the blocking call. Then, the blocking call happens so the while loop argument can return true or false. After it recieves the right token it enters the while loop, right? Then how come "Enter an integer: " doesn't print again for a second time right after the blocking call?

Comment: Sorry, @Kishore I misunderstood your response. I think I get your meaning now.

Answer (score 1):

javadoc for hasNextInt():

```
 * Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be
 * interpreted as an int value in the default radix using the
 * {@link #nextInt} method. The scanner does not advance past any input.
```

So, basically program is waiting for input at hasNextInt().
If you run in debug mode and keep debug point on first line of while loop, you will see it hits the debug point after first input.

Comment: The part that's throwing me off is that the first token is accepted in the argument of the while loop, then it prints again before actually "using" the first one. Thanks! Your debug tip helped a lot.